# Query refresh in sequence, let the first query finish before refreshing the next one

Tags: excel, vba, sequence, powerquery

```
Dim con As WorkbookConnection
For Each con In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    If InStr(1, con.Name, "Query -") Then
        With con.OLEDBConnection
            .BackgroundQuery = False
            .Refresh
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

The code refreshes the queries in sequence but doesn't wait until the first query is finished, causing the queries to get stuck.  I am stuck on how to make the queries finish and then go to the next one in the sequence in the workbook.

Comment: Shouldn't you have two `For Each` loops? One loop to set `BackgroundQuery` to `False` and then (once all are set to `False`) a second loop that refreshes them? Otherwise, you might be refreshing a dependent query whose precedent query's `BackgroundQuery` settings have not yet been set to `False`. Or does that not fix it?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to work.